# I've uploaded apk for release. How to upload other files with images?

Tags: android, publishing, google-play

I have created signed and proguarded release apk of my Android app
in IntelliJ IDEA 11. 
I uploaded it to the Google Play.
But only apk. How should I upload project images (I guess they are in test.apk.res,
classes.dex, test.apk.analigned).
I could not find a way to upload other files to Google play.

Or all images should be in the only release apk file?
But it is too small to contain images.

Comment: are you want to upload application screenshot or images used in that project ?

Answer (score 1):

> APK holds all of that program's code (such as .dex files),
>   resources(images and layouts used in projects), assets, certificates, and manifest file. As is the case
>   with many file formats, APK files can have any name needed, but must
>   end with the four character, three letter extension, .apk.

Comment: Hmm. Created apk is 6Mb, but the stuff in /out/production is 33Mb. Maybe IntelliJ IDEA created invalid release apk (with no /assets images)?

Comment: First test your application in your device and check wheather it contains all files are not.

Comment: I've tested on the device. I tryed to install after uploading via USB. Installer said that "application is not installed". I tryed another installer. The same message. Certainly the are lack of other files.

Comment: BTW, this is Libgdx project. If I check Proguard checkbox in creating release apk wizard, then I got a lot of errors concerning libgdx libraries. Okay with no proguard . Of course all was working when I uploaded to device all stuff from out/production.